# Pop Mutablelist from a MutableList kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, mutablelist

I have a `mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>` in `kotlin`. How do I pop the last element out of this list?
I have tried removeAt but it didn't work.

```
fun main() {
    val intervals:List<List<Int>> = listOf(listOf(2,9), listOf(1,8), listOf(-4, 234), listOf(22,1))
    println(intervals)    
    var sortedIntervals = intervals.toMutableList().sortedWith(Comparator<List<Int>> 
            {a, b -> a[0].compareTo(b[0])})
    println(sortedIntervals)
    sortedIntervals = sortedIntervals.map() {it -> it.toMutableList()}
    println(sortedIntervals.last())
    sortedIntervals.removeAt(sortedIntervals.size-1)
    println(sortedIntervals)
}
```

Comment: `sortedWith()` returns a new (sorted) read-only `List` - not a mutable list, so you can't call operations that mutate the list on the result (in your case, on `sortedIntervals`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`removeLastOrNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-last-or-null.html) or [`removeLast()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-last.html) functions:

```
// sortedIntervals must be MutableList to call removeLastOrNull() or removeLast()
val sortedIntervals: MutableList<...> = ...
sortedIntervals.removeLastOrNull()
```

The difference between them is that `removeLast()` function throws `NoSuchElementException` if this list is empty, but `removeLastOrNull()` doesn't throw an exception, it returns `null` if this list is empty.